# Could FP-shell kill Ergo Proxy?

Tags: ergo-proxy

This question contains spoilers for the whole anime.

> Ergo Proxy, being imperfect creation of Proxy One, is shown to be immune to sunrays (all other proxies die when in direct sunlight). It seems to me, that FP-shell, which works by emiting UV rays on contact (thus simulating sunlight and killing the proxy), shouldn't be able to hurt Ergo. However, when hit by FP-shell from Raul, it looks like it's working.

Is this explained somewhere?

Comment: When did Raul shoot Ergo? i remember Proxy One being shot but i can't remember if it was Raul and Re-L